# Use of wcf transaction with example

Tags: wcf

I read about the wcf transactions but not able to find out its use. Does anybody know any scenario where we should use wcf transaction. Realtime example would be helpful to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WCF Transaction allow us to make operations that consumers can use inside transactions. We can call a wcf service operation inside a transaction scope (for example) and ensure that our operation will be atomic. It's really helpful to ensure integrity in our operations.

For example, suppose that we have two wcf operations:

- debit(double mont,string account);
- deposit(double mont,string

If I've implemented wcf transactions I can build up a **transfer operation** mixing the **two operations** in a **transaction** and I'll be sure that there will not be any inconsistency. If any of service calls fail , the entire transaction will **rollback**.

```
try
{
  using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
  {
     IserviceClient client = new IserviceClient();
     client.debit(499,"acdf5-sdsd-4546-223-2");
     client.deposit(499,"45651-as4d-ghhd-222-1");

     scope.Complete();
  }
}
catch
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Some error occurred...");      
}
```

It can be helpful. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183708/WCF-Transactions-Brief-Introduction

EDIT: You should use transactions when the service operation changes any state (a database insert,update or delete, any file modification) although transactions are not useful when you do a simple read operation for example.

Comment: Thanks friend. Now I got clear idea on how to use wcf transaction. Still I am waiting for an example where wcf transaction is the best or only the option.

Comment: You should use transactions when the service operation changes any **state** (a database insert,update or delete, any file modification) although transactions are not useful when you do a simple **read** operation for example.